# Stationary points of a function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$F(x)=x^3+Ax+B$ has a stationary point at $(-2,3)$.

a) Find $A$ and $B$ and then find the nature of all stationary points.

Thank you!

Comment: This *must* be homework. And you *should* tell us your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$F'(x)=3x^2+A$$
so 
$$F'(-2)=0\iff 12+A=0\iff A=-12$$
and
$$F(-2)=3\iff -8+24+B=3\iff B=-13$$
now we verify that the point $(-2,3)$ is indeed a stationary point:
$$F''(-2)=-12<0$$
hence this point is a local maximum of $F$.

Can you find the other stationary point?

Answer (score 0):

Take a derivative of $F(x)$, it is going to be $3x^2+A$, when it is equal to 0, the stationary point(x=-2) gives you that $A=-12$ if you do the arithmetics. Then you have $F(x)=x^3-9x+B$.Since $F(-2)=3$, $B=-13$.

To determine the other stationar point you have to find another $x$ such that $3x^2-12=0$. When you are done finding the stationary points. Take the second derivative of $F(x)$ and determine whether $F''(-2)$ is positive or negative,similarly check whether $F''(x)$ is positive or negative for the other stationary point. If positive then its minima, if negative its maxima.